# Timing every command at windows prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I would like windows to show the time displayed for every command I run from a prompt. I don't care whether it's cmd.exe or powershell. Is this possible?

I have set up something similar on my linux and macos machines, and it's useful when I run a particularly slow command to show my teammates just how slow it is. (One hour for a commit? Here's proof!)

I've found the measure-command commandlet for powershell, but I'm not familiar enough with windows to know if there's some way to run it automatically on each command.

Comment: For those interested on how to do it on linux/macos, I use [this set of scripts](https://github.com/jichu4n/bash-command-timer).

Comment: Most everything in Windows is tracked by ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) events. You might start here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wsw/tracing) to get up to speed on the process. There are a lot of tools for analyzing the traces. It isn't trivial but certainly works.

Comment: In PowerShell, use the data from `get-history`, each line executed has a `StartExecutionTime` and `EndExecutionTime`, edit your `prompt {}` function and get the last command, substract those, and print the time as part of the prompt.

Comment: Great pointers, @TessellatingHeckler; see how it came together below. I'd used the technique before in a `Get-ExecutionTimeSpanFromHistory` function, but it hadn't occurred to me to integrate it into the prompt string, so thanks for asking the question, AFoglia.

Comment: @mklement0 :-)   I think I got the idea from [Joel Bennett's PowerLine module](https://github.com/Jaykul/PowerLine) - the screenshots there show the previous command execution time and current clock time in the top right, current folder in the top left, multiline prompt.

Answer (score 2):

A **PowerShell solution** using the approach recommended by [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler):

If you **put the following function into your `$PROFILE` file**, each prompt will show the previous command's execution duration:

```
function Prompt {
  # Calculate the previous command's execution duration (time span).
  $durationInfo = if ($he = Get-History -Count 1) {
    # Use a '0.00s' format: duration in *seconds*, with two decimal places.
    ' [{0:N2}s]' -f ($he.EndExecutionTime - $he.StartExecutionTime).TotalSeconds
  }
  # Insert the information into the default prompt string; e.g.:
  #   'PS C:\foo> ' becomes 'PS C:\foo [0.23s]> '
  "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)${durationInfo}$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

`Prompt` is the name of the function that defines the prompt string that PowerShell uses in an interactive session - see [about_Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Prompts#about-the-prompt-function).

The above prints the duration of the previous command's execution in seconds as part of the prompt string; for instance (with the above function already defined):

```
PS C:\Users\jdoe [x.xxs]> Start-Sleep 2 # x.xx secs is the PREVIOUS command's duration
PS C:\Users\jdoe [2.01s]>  # 2 seconds plus overhead
```

The approach relies on PowerShell maintaining a rich command history accessible via the [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history) cmdlet:

- It outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo) objects that have [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)-typed `.StartExecutionTime` and `.EndExecutionTime` properties.
- Subtracting the former from the latter yields a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instance.
- That instance is formatted via `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) operator, to yield a 2-decimal-digit number that expresses the duration in *seconds*.

---

If you would like to **inject the information into a *preexisting* prompt function**, put the following into your `$PROFILE` instead:

```
& {
  # Get the current definition.
  $oldFuncScriptBlock = $Function:Prompt

  # Redefine the function with the previous function's script block included:
  Set-Item Function:Prompt -Value @"
    # Calculate the previous command's execution duration (time span).
    `$durationInfo = if (`$he = Get-History -Count 1) {
      # Use a '0.00s' format: duration in *seconds*, with two decimal places.
      ' [{0:N2}s]' -f (`$he.EndExecutionTime - `$he.StartExecutionTime).TotalSeconds
    }
    # Call the old function's script block to determine its string.
    `$promptString = & { $oldFuncScriptBlock }
    # Insert the duration information into that string, under the assumption
    # that it contains a ">" character:
    `$promptString -replace '>', (`$durationInfo + '>')
"@
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really possible to manipulate `cmd` itself. There are however silly things one can do. This is a simple example using a `batch-file` to create a fake `cmd` prompt, but with the help of PowerShell. It simply uses seconds in this one as a demonstration and not milliseconds, but can be changed to use Milliseconds as well.(`powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalMilliseconds`) We are however limited to 32 bit precision, so be very aware of that! There are obviously ways around that as well though.

```
@echo off
:myprompt
set mycmd=
set /p "mycmd=prompt: "
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set start=%%I
if "%mycmd:~-4%" == ".cmd" set "mycmd=call %mycmd%"
if "%mycmd:~-4%" == ".bat" set "mycmd=call %mycmd%"
%mycmd%
for /f "delims=," %%a in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set end=%%a
set /a result=%end%-%start%
echo                                                                                        [%result% secs][%time%]
goto :myprompt
```

It is really not going to be perfectly accurate to the millisecond, but I am just proving a point.

Here is an example of one including milliseconds, bypassing the 32bit precision limitation.

```
@echo off
:myprompt
set mycmd=
set /p "mycmd=prompt: "
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set start=%%i
for /f "delims=," %%i in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalMilliSeconds"') do set mstart=%%I
if "%mycmd:~-4%" == ".cmd" set "mycmd=call %mycmd%"
if "%mycmd:~-4%" == ".bat" set "mycmd=call %mycmd%"
%mycmd%
for /f "delims=," %%a in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalSeconds"') do set end=%%a
for /f "delims=," %%a in ('powershell -command "(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date "01/01/1970") -End (Get-Date)).TotalMilliSeconds"') do set mend=%%a
set /a sres=%end%-%start%
set /a mres=%mend:~-5%-%mstart:~-5%%
echo                                                                                        [%sres%s%mres%][%time%]
goto :myprompt
```

Final Note! This is purely for demonstration purpose and by no means is it meant to be an actual accurate solution. If I have some time, I can take the script and improve it and use less `for` loops.

The real drawback here is that you need to launch the batch-file each time to use as you prompt, instead of `cmd` itself.